# VMs in different regions can't access a storage held in a third region

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-network

I have two virtual machines in two different regions; US and UK.
We also have Azure Blob Storage that was created in another region; Australia.

The Blob storage is only accessible from selected networks (no public access). When I try and add an existing network, it can't obviously find them as they are in different regions all together.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do to provide both VMs access to the storage?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable storage diagnostic logging version 2 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/manage-storage-analytics-logs?tabs=azure-portal

Parse the log file and check the IP that is trying to access the storage account and getting blocked: https://github.com/nunogabrielmonteiro/AzureStorageLogReader

Then you can whitelist the IPs in the storage firewall settings and check if you are able to access the storage account : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#managing-ip-network-rules